# Dynamically add types to interface in typescript

Tags: typescript

This is totally not necessary, but I want to know if types can be assigned dynamically to interfaces.

Suppose I have the following interface:

```js
interface UserAuth {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    auth0: SomeOtherAuthInterface;
}
```

Obviously, if `auth0` is set, then there's no need for a password (maybe there is but let's just assume there's not) and vice versa. Is there a way to type that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you label the distinct cases with a distinct value of a literal member, then you can compose a discriminated union, in which different 'variants' of your type can be distinguished by the compiler using a type guard.

```
interface UserData {
  kind:"basic"
  username: string;
}

interface UserAuth {
  kind:"authenticated",
  username: string;
  password: string;
  auth0: "something";
}

type UserRecord = UserData | UserAuth

function (record:UserRecord){
  if(record.kind==="basic"){
    console.log(record.username) 
    //console.log(record.auth0) this would be an error 
  }
  else if(record.kind==="authenticated"){
    console.log(record.username) 
    console.log(record.password) 
    console.log(record.auth0) 
  }
}
```

See this page for more information https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Omit` utility type to choose which ones you need:

```js
interface Auth { 
    username: string;
    password: string;
    auth0: SomeOtherAuthInterface;
}

type Auth0 = Omit<Auth, "password">
type BasicAuth = Omit<Auth, "auth0">
```